# Show dialog from non UI dll

Tags: c#, .net, dialog

I'm building a dll that will be used from wpf and other kind of framework (windows form, asp...). For this reason I don't want to use Messagebox. Which is the best way to send notification from dll to app and each decide the way to show the message to user (and wait an answer from user)? Somebody can help me to find the correct way?

Comment: I think you can send a string from your dll and it's the end user who will put that to a dialog box

Comment: It's better to keep it simple and just offer possibilities from you dll and not adding communication between the end user and your dll directly

Comment: Hi @user8815927, welcome to SO. I would recommend exposing an `event`.

Comment: Indeed the best ways is to use Events to send messages between modules on the same host. You can attach arbitrary arguments as well, in your case maybe a string?

You can also use an event to catch the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose an event that the consumers can subscribe to. Here is the general pattern to do this kind of thing:

You can create your own class to carry the data about the event:

```
public class NotificationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public NotificationEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
    public string Message { get; }
}
```

You then create a delegate to represent the signature of the event:

```
public delegate void OnNotificationEventHandler(SomeClass sender, NotificationEventArgs args);
```

Your class or classes can then expose this delegate as an event:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private OnNotificationEventHandler _notificationEventHandler;
    public event OnNotificationEventHandler OnNotification
    {
        add { _notificationEventHandler += value; }
        remove { _notificationEventHandler -= value; }
    }

    protected void RaiseNotificationEvent(NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        _notificationEventHandler?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Your class does something that requires consumer notification
        var args = new NotificationEventArgs("Something happened!");
        //Raise the event for the consumers who are listening (if any)
        RaiseNotificationEvent(args);
    }

}
```

Finally, your consuming classes will subscribe to this event:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.OnNotification += Obj_OnNotification;

private static void Obj_OnNotification(SomeClass sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    //Handle the notification from the class here.
    Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
}
```

The general idea is that consumers of your class only need to know that something has happened as well as details of what happened. How that **event** is consumed, handled or displayed is not the responsibility of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the library (.dll) is only intended to work with a particular UI, the library shouldn't "decide" how or if notifications get displayed. It's a separation of concerns. If a library determined that it should show a `MessageBox` then you wouldn't be able to use that same library with a web app or some out-of-sight service.

Here are two ways (not exhaustive) that we might get information from a separate library, including our own:

1. We call a function and the library returns a response. For example, it might indicate that an action succeeded or failed. The library doesn't know what type of app it's being called from or whether anyone needs to see the response. It just returns it. Your app can then receive that result and display a message.
2. A class within the library raises an event which indicates that something has happened. Same thing - it doesn't know what is listening for that even or what will happen as a result. It just raises the notification. Our app determines that in response to that event it should display a message.

When our libraries work that way they are easier to test using automated tests like unit tests and integration tests. It's easy to write a test which verifies that calling a method returns a certain result. It's much harder to verify that a MessageBox pops up.

And, as mentioned, it makes it more likely that we can use more of our code with different types of user interfaces. For those reasons it's beneficial to write as much of our code as possible in isolation from any UI, which means not including input/output behaviors that are specific to one type of UI.